# Does the hash of a file change if the filename changes?

Tags: hashsum

Does the hash of a file change if the filename or path or timestamp  or permissions change?

```
$ echo some contents > testfile
$ shasum testfile 
3a2be7b07a1a19072bf54c95a8c4a3fe0cdb35d4  testfile
```

Comment: If you need it to, then you can `zip` it.

Comment: SHA-1 & MD5 are broken but can be used. But, you will very rarely find any false negative. Most of the people prefers SHA-2 family at least.  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value  https://www.hacksandsecurity.org/posts/two-images-have-same-md5-hash-md5-collision-example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not as far as I can tell after a simple test.

```
$ echo some contents > testfile
$ shasum testfile 
3a2be7b07a1a19072bf54c95a8c4a3fe0cdb35d4  testfile
$ mv testfile newfile
$ shasum newfile 
3a2be7b07a1a19072bf54c95a8c4a3fe0cdb35d4  newfile
```

Comment: But note that if you blindly compare the outputs of `shasum`, they will not match since the output includes the filename/path (as shown in your example). A good workaround is to do something like `shasum - < testfile`.

Answer (score 33):

The hash of a file is the hash of its contents. Metadata such as the file name, timestamps, permissions, etc. have no influence on the hash.

Assuming a non-broken cryptographic hash, two files have the same hash if and only if they have the same contents. The most common such hashes are the SHA-2 family (SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512) and the SHA3 family. This does not include MD5 or SHA-1 which are broken, nor a CRC such as with `cksum` which is not a cryptographic hash.

Comment: In general, all hashes have collisions.  A non-broken cryptographic hash implies that there is no efficient way to generate a collision.

Comment: @TysonWilliams That's true but irrelevant. _If you have two files with the same hash_, and the hash is a non-broken cryptographic hash, then the two files have the same hash if and only if they have the same contents. If you could find a collision, it wouldn't be a non-broken cryptographic hash.

Comment: What you said is false.  Every (practical) hash function, even non-broken cryptographic ones, have collisions.  There are more inputs than outputs, so by the pigeonhole principle, there must be a collision.

Comment: @TysonWilliams But I never claimed that there were no collisions. Of course there are collisions. But 1. it's extremely rare to find collisions for what is generally considered to be a non-broken cryptographic hash function, and 2. if someone did find a collision then that function would no longer be a non-broken cryptographic hash function. In practical terms, if you have two files with the same SHA-256 hash, they have identical contents.

Comment: The statement "f you have two files with the same hash, and the hash is a non-broken cryptographic hash, then the two files have the same hash if and only if they have the same contents." is equivalent to "non-broken cryptographic hash [functions] have no collisions".  I agree that "In practical terms, if you have two files with the same SHA-256 hash, they have identical contents."

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Your second paragraph is superfluous and not correct. MD5 works just as your first paragraph describes.

Comment: @scottlittle What do you think is incorrect? It is possible (and easy) to create two files with the same MD5 hash.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I stated what is incorrect: "MD5 works just as your first paragraph describes." Meaning that even if MD5 is "broken" as you say, it does not invalidate the fact that it is a hash of the file's contents. In practicality, MD5 is used because it is readily available on Unix/Linux (md5sum) and quick.  Also, MD5 is commonly used to validate integrity of files sent between two companies in a professional setting as of 2020.

Comment: @scottlittle MD5 is a hash of the file's content, true. This does not contradict anything I say. An MD5 sum does not, in general, guarantee that the file has a specific content in practice. This is only true if the file was not deliberately crafted to allow later changes in the content. Using MD5 or SHA-1 to validate the integrity of files is not good practice, and makes you vulnerable to some attacks. SHA2 is as widely available and the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It's true that MD5 cannot guarantee that a file has specific content, but neither can SHA1 or SHA2- it's just a difference in probability.  Also, the way that companies use MD5 to verify integrity does not contain a security risk because the underlying file being transferred is itself encrypted with GPG, for example.

Comment: @scottlittle It's not just a difference in probability. All are suitable to defend against accidental changes, because the probability that an accidental change to a file would result in the same hash is negligible. SHA2 is suitable to defend against deliberate modification after the fact, but MD5 and SHA-1 are not. Encryption is completely irrelevant. The use of MD5 to verify integrity [has lead to severe vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities).

Comment: Encryption is not irrelevant- I was pointing out a method that MD5 is used by companies without concern for any compromise in security. Let's say an attacker uncovers the underlying file through a vulnerability in MD5, they still would have to break the GPG encryption!  My point is that MD5 as a checksum is perfectly safe for most use cases of a general purpose hash.  Your answer is deceptive for unnecessarily pointing people away from using MD5.  Plus, it does nothing to answer the original question.

Comment: @scottlittle If you aren't concerned about the security of MD5, you don't understand the security. An attack would come from whoever prepared the file, not from a man-in-the-middle during the communication. Using MD5 allows the preparer to craft a file, then switch it to another file with the same MD5 later without being detected. This is a type of attack that people tend to forget about, but that can have devastating consequences. Using SHA-256 or SHA-512 avoids this potential attack. There is no excuse for relying on MD5 in 2020.